# In bash, how can I add up all numbers from column A when column B has the same content?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

My Table looks something like this:

```
11 wordA  
16 wordB 
17 wordC 
24 wordA 
25 wordB
```

I want to add up the numbers if the words on that line match, so I can consolidate the table. The results should look something like this:

```
35 wordA
41 wordB
17 wordC
```

Help is greatly appreciated!

(P.S. Is there a way to do this using awk?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a pretty typical `awk` sort of problem.  An `awk` script to do this would look something like this:

```
{ totals[$2] += $1 }

END {
  for (i in totals)
    print totals[i], i
}
```

The first stanza creates a totals associate array keyed by column two.  The `END` block then iterates over the array and prints the total.

Answer (score 1):

In Bash 4 (which has associative arrays):

```
declare -A seen
while read -r num word
do
    [[ $word ]] && (( seen["$word"] += num ))
done < <(printf '%s\n' "${table[@]}")

for word in "${!seen[@]}"
do
    printf '%d %s\n' "${seen["$word"]}" "$word"
done
```

You can replace `<(printf '%s\n' "${table[@]}")` with `<(some_command)` or `filename` depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

pipe it to

```
awk '{s[$2]+=$1}END{ for(i in s) print s[i], i }'
```